# I can not login in Cakephp 2.4

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I have problem with Auth in Cakephp 2.4 , can not login and I can not find error in my code

My AppController

http://pastebin.com/hmju7SHM

user Model

http://pastebin.com/BMsuMFan

my login method

```
public function cpadmin_login() 
    {
        $this->pageTitle = __('Login page', true);
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
            }
        }
    }
```

while try do login by username/password not thing happen and sql log no password check

sql log

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`name`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`role_id`, `User`.`active`, `User`.`created`, `Role`.`id`, `Role`.`name`, `Role`.`roles` FROM `cairotweet`.`users` AS `User` LEFT JOIN `cairotweet`.`roles` AS `Role` ON (`User`.`role_id` = `Role`.`id`) WHERE `User`.`username` = 'admin' AND `User`.`active` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Show your AuthComponent configuration and the login form, please.

Comment: did you allowed the cpadmin_login in the auth component ?, if you dont, the user as no access to your login method

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to take a look at the tutorial **Simple Authentication and Authorization Application** from the cakePHP website:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/part-two.html

Following all steps you will config quickly Acl and Auth, database, controllers and models.

Comment: I do it bofer but nothing change

Comment: I added more two links.. you have followed all these instructions?